# How to cross convert older ad&d with newer d&d editions or vise versa

Tags: conversion

I want to use my ad & d 1st ed books and blend them in with my sons 3.0 core books, and 5th ed. What is the BEST way to do this. Things like, converting/switching AC to positive = better AC rather than lower AC = better AC. As well as combat tables, save throws etc. Is there a straight forward conversions to assist?
Psionoic and spells, also monsters NPC's and moduals from the early '80s.
Converting Thac0 to an easier combat form, stuff like this.
Shurly, I am not the rare few, that want to play using old monsters with new, old campaigns with newer books and breath life back into these old tomes.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is going to be too broad to answer in a single question, but probably start with the idea that you're going to use only one set of rules and only convert things that don't already exist in that set. Consider using separate questions to ask about converting characters you already have, specific old monsters, and maybe individual modules. (Some of those have already been converted by WotC or others.)

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear, because I'm not sure what end result you want out of blending AD&D 1e, D&D 3e, and D&D 5e together. We can advise on converting particular features of one edition into another edition, but it's hard to know what to suggest when you want to convert arbitrary stuff into a homebrew blend. You could start by defining a particular "home" system you want to use -- do you want to play in AD&D 1e, D&D 3e, or D&D 5e? -- and identifying what is missing or unsatisfying from that system that you want to bring in from other editions, then asking us how to convert that.

Comment: In the "Related" bar on the right side of your screen, there are a number of "how can I convert?" questions shown, that will probably give you a good overview of the steps to take here.

Comment: Are you just wanting to know how to convert AD&D monsters and adventures to a later D&D edition? That's a question we *could* help with, if that's what you're after. (But we would need you to say so clearly, preferably with an [edit] to the question, and pick *one* edition to convert to.)